# In a bash shell script, how to rename multiple files, keeping only the numbers and the extension of the original file names?

Tags: bash, text-processing, terminal, regular-expression, rename

I have a directory with a bunch of files with names like this:

- generic name- dd -01 _.txt
- generic name- dd -02 _.txt
- generic name- dd -03 _.txt
- generic name- dd -04 _.txt

And I want to rename all of them, keeping only the numbers and the extension like this:

- 01.txt
- 02.txt
- 03.txt
- 04.txt

How can I do this using a shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Perl rename

I would use (perl-)rename. Distros ship two types of rename, so you can check if you have the perl version of rename installed with

```
$ rename --version
perl-rename 1.9
```

Run it with `-n` to test the command as a "dry run".

```
$ rename 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]*).*/\1.txt/' * -n
generic name- dd -01 _.txt -> 01.txt
generic name- dd -02 _.txt -> 02.txt
generic name- dd -03 _.txt -> 03.txt
generic name- dd -04 _.txt -> 04.txt
```

When you are happy run the command itself.

```
$ rename 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]*).*/\1.txt/' *
```

### Explanation

- `rename 's/foo/bar/' *`: rename all files (`*`), replacing the regex `foo` with `bar`.
- `[^0-9]*([0-9]*).*`: match all non-numerical characters `[^0-9]*`, followed by numerical characters, which are enclosed in a "capturing group" `([0-9]*)`, followed by the rest of the characters `.*`. This will match the whole filename.
- `\1.txt`: replace the filename with the captured group `\1`, appended with `.txt`.

## The other rename

If you have the simpler rename installed, you will see something like this instead.

```
$ rename --version
rename from util-linux 2.33.1
```

In this case you can use the following two commands:

```
$ rename 'generic name- dd -' '' *
$ rename ' _' '' *
```

But I strongly recommend learning perl-rename instead.

Answer (score 0):

We can do with below one liner. Tested it. But it needs to be executed from the current folder where file is present.

```
for file in *generic*.txt; do newname=$(echo $file | awk -F"-" '{print $3}' | sed 's/ _//g'); mv "$file" $newname;done
```

if you want to run from different folder you can try with below script

```
#!/bin/bash


SRCFLDR=yoursourcefolder
for file in $SRCFLDR/*generic*.txt;do
        newname=$(echo $file | awk -F"-" '{print $3}' | sed 's/ _//g')
        mv "$file" $newname
        echo $file has been renamed to $newname
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple script should do it:

```
for f in *[0-9]*.*; do
  base=${f%.*}
  mv -- "$f" "${base//[^0-9]}.${f##*.}"
done
```